# Sorting a Linq Query

Tags: c#, linq

I cant for the life of me figure out why this List will not sort properly. Can someone point out what I am doing wrong?

```
List<WNBlogPost> posts = new List<WNBlogPost>();

IEnumerable<WNBlogPost> orderedPosts = (
    from p in posts
    select p
).OrderByDescending(c => c.ID);

foreach (WNBlogPost post in orderedPosts) {
    //output post to page
}
```

I am adding items to the posts list in loop, but the order they are added to the list is the same order they appear in after I add OrderByDescending().

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Why would you use that syntax instead of `posts.OrderByDescending(c => c.ID)`?

Comment: Firstly what type is WNBlogPost.ID? Secondly you wouldn't happen to be looking at `posts` instead of  `orderedPosts` by any chance?

Comment: WNBlogPost.ID is an int field

Comment: @Duane: perhaps a silly question, but what does simply writing out `post.ID` look like?

Comment: so it turns out i am a complete idiot. the code was working properly, but a user control feeding my data was set to return the first 50 posts instead of the last 50. The sorting was working correctly, i was just sorting the wrong set. Thanks for all the help everyone

Answer (score 12, accepted):

LINQ queries (without external effort) do not introduce side-effects into the collections they operate on. Therefore, `OrderByDescending` only presents a sorted *view* of `posts` which you can access via `orderedPosts`.

```
// hat-tip: @JimSchubert
foreach (var post in orderedPosts)
{
    Frob(post); // these will be frobbed in descending order
}
```

If you would like to sort the actual list itself, you should use [`List<T>.Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3da4abas.aspx):

```
// utilize the Comparison<T> overload of List<T>.Sort to perform a
// descending sort based on the post ID
posts.Sort((post1, post2) => -post1.ID.CompareTo(post2.ID));
```

Comment: Also, you then have to enumerate over `orderedPosts` for it to be useful :D